# Pagination on Java Swing JTextArea with print simple Text

Tags: java, swing, pagination, jtextarea

I am Newbie here. I am working on Bank project. As per client need they want there report in simple text format using `applet` with `JTextArea`. JTextArea content should be in simple text in Table form with page header and footer including pagination on next page.

So i am getting confuse how to achieve this without css/html/Jtable...:) Please help me to do this. If someone has code please send it on my email id sndpdevhare10@gmail.com.

Thanks in Advance. I hope someone will help me to solve this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! *Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)*

Comment: I have not removed your e-mail address but strongly recommend that you delete it right away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without better specifications the best I can do for you is a easy to understand tutorial.

[Watch tutorials 20-31](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLE7E8B7F4856C9B19)
It has everything you need to know for your project.